# swift combine flatmap sequential operation

Tags: swift, combine, flatmap

```
extension CLGeocoder {
    func reverseGeocodeLocationPublisher(_ location: CLLocation, preferredLocale locale: Locale? = nil) -> AnyPublisher<CLPlacemark, Error> {
        Future<CLPlacemark, Error> { promise in
            self.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: locale) { placemarks, error in
                guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                    return promise(.failure(error ?? CLError(.geocodeFoundNoResult)))
                }
                return promise(.success(placemark))
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

$stations.flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { (station) -> AnyPublisher<CLPlacemark, Error> in
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: station.latitude, longitude: station.longitude)
            self.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocationPublisher(location)

        }.eraseToAnyPublisher().sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            print("done")
        }, receiveValue: { placemark in
            print("placemark:", placemark)
        }).store(in: &cancellableSet)
```

error:
`Instance method 'flatMap(maxPublishers:_:)' requires the types 'Published<[Station]>.Publisher.Failure' (aka 'Never') and 'Error' be equivalent`

What I am trying to achieve is i have a list of stations which contains `location` and I want to `reverseGeocodeLocation` sequentially

Comment: Really all you have to do is read the error message. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is due to `Publishers.FlatMap` that requires that the `Failure` of the upstream and the new publisher be the same. `FlatMap` returns a `Failure` of `Error` type, but `$stations` has a `Failure` of `Never`, so you need to adjust that with:

```
.setFailureType(to: Error.self)
```

Since `stations` is an array, and you want to handle each element sequentially, you'd need to use a `Publishers.Sequence` publisher (available through `Array.publisher`), which will emit each element one-by-one:

```
stations.publisher
```

Putting these two things together:

```
$stations.flatMap { stations in
            stations.publisher
         }
         .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
         .flatMap { station in 
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: station.latitude, ...)
            return self.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocationPublisher(location)
         }
```

Comment: this compiles but doesnt work 
`filteredStations.publisher.setFailureType(to: Error.self).flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { (station) -> AnyPublisher<CLPlacemark, Error> in
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: station.latitude, longitude: station.longitude)
            return self.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocationPublisher(location)
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher().sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            print("done")
        }, receiveValue: { placemark in
            print("placemark:", placemark)
        }).store(in: &cancellableSet)`

Comment: this doesnt compile
`$filteredStations.setFailureType(to: Error.self).flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { (station) -> AnyPublisher<CLPlacemark, Error> in
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: station.latitude, longitude: station.longitude)
            return self.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocationPublisher(location)
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher().sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            print("done")
        }, receiveValue: { placemark in
            print("placemark:", placemark)
        }).store(in: &cancellableSet)`

Comment: the error is Value of type 'Publishers.SetFailureType<Published<[Station]>.Publisher, Error>.Output' (aka 'Array<Station>') has no member 'latitude'

Comment: @user3165940. This looks like an unrelated error, no? What is `filteredStations`?

Comment: its this  @Published var filteredStations = [Station]()

Comment: @user3165940, ok, so this is an unrelated error. In your `flatMap`'s closure, the parameter is an array of `[Station]`, whereas you are expecting each object `Station`, hence the error. (You really should read error messages - they're often informative)

Comment: @user3165940 - updated the answer, This should address your concerns